# Swift 2: Instance Member cannot be used on type "View Controller"

Tags: ios, swift, class, uilabel

Im new to swift and I'm experimenting with classes and methods! I have been looking all over google and stackoverflow to find an answer! I have read multiple posts with the same problem but they still don't help me! I have written swift code for a bigger app but decided to write a small portion so I get the same idea. Im trying to update a UILabel's text with a method inside a class when a certain button is pressed. Im trying to change the text by `MyLabel.text = "text"` but its giving me the error of 'Instance member cannot be used on type "view controller"' Please help me find whats wrong with it and explain it! Thank you so much! Here is my code bellow:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

class Door {

    var DoorLocked = false

    func lockDoor() {
        DoorLocked = true
        MyLabel.text = "The door is locked!"
    }

    func unlockDoor() {
        DoorLocked = false
        MyLabel.text = "The door is unlocked!"
    }

    init() {
        MyLabel.text = "This is a door!"
    }
}

var DoorStatus = Door()

@IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func LockButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    DoorStatus.lockDoor()
}

@IBAction func UnlockButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    DoorStatus.unlockDoor()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Where's the view controller with all of these outlets and actions?

Comment: @TroyT I updated it ! Thanks!

Comment: @BaseZen How do I add failing line of code? In the lockDoor() and unlockDoor() methods where they do 'MyLabel.text'

Comment: This is clearly an architectural problem - first, the model class is _inside_ the view controller. Second, the model class shouldn't be accessing the view controller's properties directly like that.

Comment: At the point of the construction of door the Label will not yet be set

Comment: @TroyT So I should move class Door above the viewController class? and could you explain how the model class (by model class im assuming you mean class Door, sorry Im new!) shouldnt be accessing the view controllers properties directy?

Comment: Just keep in mind your questions here are approaching the rough equivalent of "can you teach me the fundamentals of user-interface programming".  You don't really have a specific technical question. You can copy various code to "just make it work", but you may want to escalate the effort to a course, tutorial, or self-teaching through a whole set of chapters of a book and lay some real groundwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a architectural point of view, I would argue that it does not make sense for the `Door` class to know of any labels on that specific `ViewController`. Further, the Swift language, does not allow you to access that label inside the nested class. Instead, consider doing something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class Door {

        var DoorLocked = false

        func lockDoor() {
            DoorLocked = true
        }

        func unlockDoor() {
            DoorLocked = false
        }

    }

    var DoorStatus = Door()

    @IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func LockButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        DoorStatus.lockDoor()
        MyLabel.text = "The door is locked!"
    }

    @IBAction func UnlockButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        DoorStatus.unlockDoor()
        MyLabel.text = "The door is unlocked!"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MyLabel.text = "This is a door!"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing it like that makes a lot more sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The inner class `Door` doesn't know anything about `MyLabel`. Inner classes don't share variables with the class they're declared in, unlike other languages. It's *pretty* much like the `Door` class is declared at top level along-side `ViewController`. You need a good bit more background to separate a model & ViewController into separate classes and then make them communicate properly with a protocol/delegate pattern. Unless you're following a template for exactly how, first just do everything within `ViewController`. So declare your model variable `doorLocked` directly within `ViewController`, and update it along with changing the text of the label directly within the `@IBAction`.

Again caveat that this is just learning iOS & Swift at a basic level, then proper MVC design should come next.

Also, all variables should start with lower-case. Every time you start a variable with uppercase, it hurts the eyes because it looks like a class or other type rather than storage.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure I understand what you are saying, I should just get rid of the door class and make lockDoor and unlockDoor functions? Also, I normally camalCase but I just did that fast!

Comment: It pains me to say, because I have to force my students to use good model/view/controller separation all the time, but yes, drop the Door class completely for now. Use a single state variable `doorLocked`, and have a *single* `@IBAction` function `toggleDoor()` so that you're forced to actually *use* the state variable to determine what action to take. That way your "model" (single Boolean property) is put to good use.

Comment: Thank you and I will be looking into a better swift course!